# Element SESSIONID is undefined in SESSION - CF9

Tags: session, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, sessionid

please help. We have a CFM system that works 100% for most of the users except a few (less than 10 out of 3000+ users). All users can login without a problem and session variables be set. The login page then send them to the dashboard. We then use the `SessionID`, among other factors, to encrypt the URL string.

However for the 10- users, when they reach the dashboard, we get the error

```
Element SESSIONID is undefined in SESSION
```

The only resolution we have to far is for them to close the browser entirely then start from scratch. Everyone else is working fine.

Sure enough, the session struct dump has no `SessionID`. I know that the `sessionid` is basically `AppName` + `CFID` + `CFToken`. How can I recreate the SessionID without sending them back to the login or losing the already set session variables?

Comment: When you dump the session scope, what is there?

Comment: Well from my side everything is fine. But from the users side, every other variable we set after login is there... There is no `CFID`, `CFToken` or `SessionID`. However there is a `URLToken` that has the value `CFID=3876607&CFTOKEN=26913357`

Comment: Are you using J2EE sessions? Do you have any code that does something like `structDelete(session, 'sessionid')` or anything like that?

Comment: I have a code that deletes the session, then expire the other variables.  

    <cfset ServerName=LCase(CGI.SERVER_NAME)>  
    <cfset structClear(Session)>  
    <cfloop condition="listLen(ServerName,'.') gte 2">  
    <cfloop list="CFID,CFTOKEN,CFMAGIC,SESSIONID,JSESSIONID" index="CookieName">  
        <cfcookie expires="NOW" name="#CookieName#" domain=".#ServerName#">  
        <cfcookie expires="NOW" name="#CookieName#" domain="#ServerName#">  
        <cfcookie expires="NOW" name="#CookieName#">  
    </cfloop>  
    <cfset ServerName=listRest(ServerName,".")>  
</cfloop>

Comment: However this code works 100% for the 3000 other users. My confusion is that only about 10 out of 3671 users we have, have the session problem.

Answer (score 1):

SESSIONID includes "AppName + CFID + CFToken". So, whenever you want to perform logout functionality you need to clear CFID and CFToken both.If you put below codes under logout functionality. It will be fixed.

StructClear(session);`enter code here`
   StructDelete(cookie, 'CFID');
   StructDelete(cookie, 'CFToken');

Comment: What benefit does it add to delete a cookie when you have made it expire? And why does it work for 3000+ users but not 10- users?